# Android widget update strangeness w/ sqlite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, widget

So I'm making a sorta timer widget that pulls info from an sqlite database. Looks to work as expected when there is only 1 entry in the database but when there is more than 1 the widget seems to flicker between the values. E.g. 1 second you will see the first value then the next 2nd will be the next value etc. Here is the code and please note the command fetchDecks(5) which looks at the reminder value and if it's past current time it will not show. So once entry 1 time is up it should move onto entry 2.

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private DBadapter mDbHelper;
    Cursor note;
    private long reminder;
    private String title, summary;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
        mDbHelper = new DBadapter(context);
        mDbHelper.open();
        note = mDbHelper.fetchDecks(5);
        note.moveToFirst();
        reminder = note.getLong(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mDbHelper.KEY_REMINDER));
        title = note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mDbHelper.KEY_TITLE));
        summary = note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(mDbHelper.KEY_SUMMARY));  
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 1000);
    }

    private class MyTime extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;

    public MyTime(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
        this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        long diff = reminder - current;
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.TextView01, countDown(diff));
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, title);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);          
    }

    private String countDown(long result) {
        String mMinutes,mSeconds,mHours, mDays;
        int seconds = (int) (result / 1000) % 60 ;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            mSeconds = "0" + Integer.toString(seconds);
        } 
        else if (seconds <= 9) {
            mSeconds = "0" + Integer.toString(seconds);
        } else {
            mSeconds = Integer.toString(seconds);
        }

        int minutes = (int) ((result / (1000*60)) % 60);
        if (minutes == 0) {
            mMinutes = "0" + Integer.toString(minutes);
        } 
        else if (minutes <= 9) {
            mMinutes = "0" + Integer.toString(minutes);
        } else {
            mMinutes = Integer.toString(minutes);
        }

        int hours   = (int) ((result / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
        if (hours == 0) {
            mHours = "0" + Integer.toString(hours);
        } 
        else if (hours <= 9) {
            mHours = "0" + Integer.toString(hours);
        } else {
            mHours = Integer.toString(hours);
        }

        int days = (int) (result / (1000*60*60*24));
        if (days == 0) {
            mDays = "0" + Integer.toString(days);
        } 
        else if (days <= 9) {
            mDays = "0" + Integer.toString(days);
        } else {
            mDays = Integer.toString(days);
        }
        String tRemaining = mDays + " days | " + mHours + " hours | " + mMinutes + " mins | " + mSeconds + " secs";     
        return tRemaining;
    }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Please show `fetchDecks`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was an issue in the xml file causing it.